# scroll to top on react react-router-dom page change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I'm using `react-router-dom` for implementing routing of my reactjs App!
but I have an issue with this , in which I can't find any working solution for scroll to top on page changing. can any body help me???

here is my routing piece of code:

```
    <BrowserRouter  basename={basename}> 
          <Switch>
                    <MobilePage hasNav navType="primary" exact path={`/restaurant`} component={VendorList} />
                    <MobilePage hasNav navType="primary" path={`/restaurant/:vendorCode`} component={VendorDetails} /> 
          </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

add to `VendorList` and `VendorDetails` in `componentDidMount()` function `window.scrollTo(0,0)`

Comment: You should also reset keyboard focus at the same time as scrolling to top. I wrote a thing to take care of it: https://github.com/oaf-project/oaf-react-router

Comment: @danielnixon How can I use the basename parameter with the oaf-react-router? It seems to be ignored.

Comment: @danielnixon I was using the basename attribute of the BrowserRouter tag, but I suppose that I will now need to move it as a config property of createBrowserHistory ?

Comment: @danielnixon I managed to make it work by moving the basename from the BrowserRouter "tag attribute", to the config property of createBrowserHistory, but I also had to downgrade to history@4.10.1 because history@5.0.0 has removed support for basename.

Comment: oaf-react-router is stuck on history@4 because that's what react-router uses: https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/package.json#L29

Answer (score 5):

I am currently using the react-router-dom v5 (most of these solutions that I found was geared to v4) and I was surprised to not find a solution for pages to load to the top in a transition.

What solved my problem was installing [react-router-scroll-top](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-router-scroll-top) and put the wrapper in the  like this:

```js
const App = () => (
  <Router>
    <ScrollToTop>
      <App/>
    </ScrollToTop>
  </Router>
)
```

and everything worked as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Install the plugin below
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-router-scroll-top

```
import ScrollToTop from 'react-router-scroll-top'

const App = () => (
<Router>
  <ScrollToTop>
     <App/>
  </ScrollToTop>
</Router>
  )
<ScrollToTop/>
```